# How to avoid page visit count on refresh?

Tags: php, laravel

I have implemented page visit count in my application. Every time user clicks certain links the page count of that model increases.

Migration

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigInteger('reads')->unsigned()->default(0)->index();
});
```

Model:

```
public function incrementReadCount() {
    $this->reads++;
    return $this->save();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function show(Post $post)
    {
        $post->incrementReadCount();

        return view('post.show', compact($post));
    }
```

This is what I have tried so far. But count increase as page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `session` to get this done. Use the following in your `show()` method.
I use something like the following:

```
$view_key = 'blog_' . $post->id;
    // Check if blog session key exists
    // If not, update view_count and create session key
    if (!Session::has($view_key)) {
        $post->incrementReadCount();
        Session::put($view_key, 1);
    }
```

Edit: This is based on my code. Please change the specifics where needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session to store the current page url. And each time a user navigates, check if the user requested url is same as session stored url. If same do not increase the page count.
And remember to update the session each time.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of considerations in building a visitor counter.
Will each entry increase the counter by 1?
If not, how to identify if the user has already visited the site?
Are these registered users, ID by IP address, session ...
Will MYSQL meet the number of queries if the site is working on a large scale

In any case, you should take a look here:
https://www.iditect.com/how-to/54096981.html

Answer (score -1):

you should have user_id or user_ip column too

and before increasing the count, check that if the user_id or user_ip is in table or not

if it is dont increase and if it is not increase it and save user_id or user_ip to db for next checks

Comment: This won't solve his problem. Also what ever you are saying will be obsolete if the user tries to reach the link again another time.

Comment: he should have a table for that. and save user_id and post_id in that .and every time check if there is user_id and post_id for current user and post or not
this is the correct way of doing this that i saw in many youtube episodes also but good luck anyway

Comment: Well as you can see from his code, he already has a column to count the visitor against the post. So making another table is irrelevant.

Comment: at first line of my answer i told him he should have at least one another column in that table too!!
but the correct way is to have another table for this